# Performance problems after migrating ASP.NET Web Forms application using LINQ-to-SQL to SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql, webforms

I’ve been doing some maintenance on a legacy web application, implemented with ASP.NET Web Forms, VB.NET, and using LINQ-to-SQL for data access.

We recently migrated the application from SQL Server 2005 to SQL Server 2016. Since then, reports that had previously taken several seconds to generate are now taking several minutes instead.

The design of the report generation is somewhat sub-optimal. To generate a single summary report, we are running about a 100 queries, and then piecing together the results in the code for the final report. I would have preferred a design that had one query do all the work in the database.

We had our database administrator run a profiling tool while we were testing. In the trace table he provided, I saw about two hundred entries linked to the report generation. There were just over one hundred data access queries using **sp_executesql**  (generated by LINQ-to-SQL), each taking only a couple milliseconds at most. There are about the same number of calls to **sp_reset_connection**, but the DB admin asserts that there is nothing unexpected about that. And he doesn’t see any red flags from his own inspection of the trace table.

Unfortunately the administrator of the web server has no profiling tools available to run while we are testing, and I can’t run the application on my local machine to do my own profiling.

A few more details on our configuration:

- Windows Server 2016
- IIS 10
- .NET Framework 4.6.2
- SQL Server 2016 (13.0.5366.0)

Any suggestions on how we might approach resolving this?

Comment: There was a big change to the cardinality estimator in 2014; there's a lot of articles on the subject.#

Comment: @Larnu Do you think changes in the cardinal estimator could account for the slowness, even when each individual query is running in a couple of milliseconds? It seems like the time between the queries accounts for the great bulk of the total time required by the report generation.

Comment: @Micheal; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

Sending too many requests to the database server caused by bad architecture or method you loading your data.
when you are loading data with "Lazy loading" (that is default method in Linq 2 SQL) method and try to load related data in the "foreach" block "Too many requests happened.

**Solution for loading problem: Eager Loading**

```
DataLoadOptions Load = new DataLoadOptions();  
Load.LoadWith < Department > (d => d.Employees);
```

**Detail log about how you loading data:**

```
dbContext.Log = Response.Output;  //<or any way you trace, debug or ...>
```

also, "sp_reset_connection" occurs when a SQL connection returns to the connection pool, now this should not be a problem.

**read more info:**
https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-in-linq-to-sql/